# Consulta en BBDD Mysql no me devuelve todos los resultados

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo una base de datos Mysql y estoy haciendo una lectura para capturar el número de un id secundario de un usuario y al realizar la consulta no devuelve todos los resultados, sin embargo en Workbench veo muchos más.

Esta es la consulta:

```
 $resultadoUsuario = $mysqli->query(
     "SELECT * FROM `shop_users` WHERE `shop_id` like '37'"
 );
```

Ese 37 es el ID para buscar el número de usuarios que, en Workbench como digo aparecen un montón y aquí me da esto:

```
string(3) "690" string(3) "691" string(3) "692" string(3) "693" string(3) "694" string(3) "695"
```

Qué puede ser?

Comment: Prueba like ‘%37%’ para todos los que contengan 37 y = ‘37’ para el que sea igual a 37

Comment: Una duda shop_id es de tipo entero en tu tabla?

Comment: Con el %37% tampoco... Y si, es entero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu código

```
$resultadoUsuario = $mysqli->query(
     "SELECT * FROM `shop_users` WHERE `shop_id` like '37'"
 );
```

Sin el contexto de tu problema, al parecer quieres obtener todos los usuarios que contengan `37` en la columna shop_id, asumo que por eso usas la clausula `like`. Si ese el caso, deberías usar like con el comodín `%`; ya sea al inicio `'%37'`(si quieres que sea 37 sin importar lo que lo precede), al final `'37%'`(si quieres que se incluya todo lo que sigue despues de 37) o al inicio y al final `'%37%'` (si quieres que aparezca todo lo que contenga 37); ya que sin este comodín estarías obteniendo un operador `=` en la consulta sql.

Es decir tu consulta SQL actual se interpretaría como:

```
SELECT * FROM `shop_users` WHERE `shop_id` = 37
```

Intenta

```
$resultadoUsuario = $mysqli->query(
   "SELECT * FROM `shop_users` WHERE `shop_id` like '%37%'"
);
```

y obtendrás mas resultados.

**===Edición===**

Al leer los comentarios mencionas que shop_id es de tipo entero, por lo que podrias hacer un cambio a tu consulta convirtiendo a cadena el campo shop_id

```
$resultadoUsuario = $mysqli->query(
   "SELECT * FROM `shop_users` WHERE CAST(`shop_id` as CHAR) like '%37%'"
);
```

Comment: Perfecto, esto es justo lo que necesitaba. Gracias.